# Uncaught TypeError: $.number is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to get server stats from api. Backend side working but the javascript side not.
I'm getting this error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: $.number is not a function
```

.

```
 function getStats(auto=true) {
        var rStart = Date.now();
        if (window.rServerID == "home") {
            rURL = "<?php echo site_url('index.php/api/stats'); ?>";
        } else {
            rURL = "<?php echo site_url('index.php/api/stats/'); ?>" ;
        }
        $.getJSON(rURL, function(data) {
            
            // Open Connections
            var rCapacity = Math.ceil((data.open_connections / data.total_connections) * 100);
            if (isNaN(rCapacity)) { rCapacity = 0; }
            $(".active-connections .entry").html($.number(data.open_connections, 0));
            $(".active-connections .entry-percentage").html($.number(data.total_connections, 0));
            $(".active-connections .progress-bar").prop("aria-valuenow", rCapacity);
            $(".active-connections .progress-bar").css("width", rCapacity.toString() + "%");
            $(".active-connections .sr-only").html(rCapacity.toString() + "%");
```

Comment: What do you expect `$.number()` to be? The error message is pretty clear.

Comment: Actually I don't know. This javascript code writted by another person. I just want to show numbers in html side. if $.number is useless i can delete :) thank you

Comment: It may have been something that some other code added to the base jQuery object in another project. It looks like it probably attempts to convert a string to a number, and if that fails it uses the second argument as a default value.

Comment: yes you're right now i realized.. how can i use this with the same logic?

Comment: The code used looks similar to this plugin https://github.com/customd/jquery-number (This plugin's code hasn't been updated since 2015). PD: I only needed to google "jQuery $ .number" to find this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. this function ($.number) comes from jquery-number library.
https://github.com/customd/jquery-number

Thank you all :)